# minMaxLoc function - How to access the variables?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a question, some of you might find it a stupid one but I am stuck on a thing, hopefully you can help me.

I am using the following function in order to find the location of the brightest and the darkest pixel of an image:

```
darkest,brightest,dark_loc,bright_loc=cv2.minMaxLoc(img)
```

Now I need the values from dark_loc and bright_loc (both on the x and y axis in difference variables a and b) in order to calculate the distance from the centre of the image. I need those values in order to track a laser beam on a screen. Could you please help me to extract the values?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Vassil

P.S.: I am not sure if it's of any relevance but I am doing this using OpenCV on an RPi 2B.

Comment: Hint: **print dark_loc, bright_loc** so you can see the format of what **minMaxLoc** gave you.  That will likely allow you to answer your own question.  I suspect that they are simple tuples of coordinates, so you can get x and y with subscripts 0 and 1.

Comment: In the future, please skip your intro sentence about whether this is a stupid question or not and get right to the point. StackOverflow tries to record questions for future readers... extraneous commentary just impedes search engines sorting the questions correctly.

Comment: Thanks dude but I have printed dark and bright loc on the screen. Is there a code or something ( i am fairly knew to python) that can extract the data from the format of (623:312) to variables x=623; y=312.

Cheers